# a [href] not working in phpmailer

Tags: yii, phpmailer

I have used phpmailer as the library for sending email using YiiMail extension. I have use layout that contains several text including the link such as `<a href="http://link">Test</a>`

But when I include that `link` My Email status is sending success but I don't get any email coming.

When I not included Email it successfully sent.

What the problems I got? Anyone can help
**[Edited]**

This is my code and  I have tested that it `return true`

```
$link=Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('user/resetpassword',array('h'=>$this->Hash));
$message='<div style="clear:both"></div>
        <h2 style="float:none">Reset Password - Lawang Code</h2>
        <div class="hr biru"></div>
        <p>
            Seseorang telah berusaha untuk mereset password anda  <br/>
            Jika memang aksi ini benar silahkan ikuti tautan berikut ini  <hr/>
            <div style="margin:0 auto;width:200px">
            <a style="display:block;width:100px;background:#09C;color:white;padding:10px;text-decoration:none" href="'.$link.'">Reset Password</a>
            </div>

        </p>';
$mail = new YiiMailer('notification', array(
        'judul' => "Reset Password - Lawang Code",
        'pesan'=>'Seseorang telah berusaha untuk mereset password anda  <br/>
            Jika memang aksi ini benar silahkan ikuti tautan berikut ini  <hr/>',
        'link'=>$link,
        'linkLabel'=>"Reset Password",
    ));
            //render HTML mail, layout is set from config file or with        $mail->setLayout('layoutName')
    $mail->render();
    $from=Yii::app()->params->adminEmail;
    //set properties as usually with PHPMailer
    $mail->From = trim($from);
    $mail->FromName = "Lawang Code";
    $mail->Subject = "Aksi Reset Password - Lawang Code";

    $mail->AddAddress(trim($this->Email));
    //send
    if ($mail->Send()) {
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        return true;
        //echo 'Success.';
    } else {
        //echo 'Error while sending email: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    }
```

It has

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable `IsHTML` by passing `true`

```
$mailer->IsHTML(true);
```

check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5686798/829533

Comment: I have use the HTML. ALl html works well but not for `a[href]`.. Is there any filtering allowing tags configuration in mail?

Comment: I have added the code. and It has default to HTML content with the layout I have added. There is also charset to UTF-8.

Comment: Yes and still not work.. The one strange is if I remove that tag it can be sent successfully